# Getting an html link to activate a css image map hover

Tags: css, image, dictionary, menu, hover

I've looked at some other questions but not finding anything that explains this to me. I'm fairly beginner at this. This is for this website: http://www.lostpathway.com/village.html
I have an image map in css (see below). I have it so when you hover over the map and click on an area, it goes to the corresponding webpage. I also have a css menu at the top of the page that has a hover effect on the menu and also goes to the corresponding page. What I want to do is link the menu and the image map so that when you hover over the menu area it also activates the image map hover and vice versa. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Any help would be welcome.

```
    /* Visible image map container */
#puttygut {
position: relative;
width: 900px;
height: 697px;
border: 2px solid;
background: #205a4d url(./villagemap.gif) no-repeat;
margin: 0em auto;
padding: 0;
}

/* List styling */
#puttygut li {
display: block;
position: absolute;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

/* Link styling */
#puttygut a {
display: block;
text-indent: -9999px;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
cursor: default;
}

/* position on the image (z-index goes here) */
#memory {left: 171px; top: 15px; z-index: 10;}
#timberlost {left: 2px; top: 249px;}
#greyhorse {left: 248px; top: 291px;}
#visions {left: 390px; top: 355px;}
#cottage {left: 617px; top: 39px; z-index: 10;}
#windmill {left: 569; top: 462;}


/* width & height */
#memory a {width: 220px; height: 150px;}
#timberlost a {width: 185px; height: 232px;}
#greyhorse a {width: 152px; height: 130px;}
#visions a {width: 105px; height: 75px;}
#cottage a {width: 126px; height: 120px;}
#windmill a {width: 63px; height: 80;}

/* hover image position */
#memory a:hover {background: url(./villagemap.gif) -31px -740px no-repeat;}
#timberlost a:hover {background: url(./villagemap.gif) -610px -951px no-repeat; }
#greyhorse a:hover {background: url(./villagemap.gif) -622px -769px no-repeat;}
#visions a:hover {background: url(./villagemap.gif) -65px -970px no-repeat;}
#cottage a:hover {background: url(./villagemap.gif) -384px -939px no-repeat;}
#windmill a:hover {background: url(./villagemap.gif) -351px -783px no-repeat;}/* Visible image map container */
#puttygut {
position: relative;
width: 900px;
height: 697px;
border: 2px solid;
background: #205a4d url(./villagemap.gif) no-repeat;
margin: 0em auto;
padding: 0;
}

/* List styling */
#puttygut li {
display: block;
position: absolute;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

/* Link styling */
#puttygut a {
display: block;
text-indent: -9999px;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
cursor: default;
}

/* position on the image (z-index goes here) */
#memory {left: 171px; top: 15px; z-index: 10;}
#timberlost {left: 2px; top: 249px;}
#greyhorse {left: 248px; top: 291px;}
#visions {left: 390px; top: 355px;}
#cottage {left: 617px; top: 39px; z-index: 10;}
#windmill {left: 569; top: 462;}


/* width & height */
#memory a {width: 220px; height: 150px;}
#timberlost a {width: 185px; height: 232px;}
#greyhorse a {width: 152px; height: 130px;}
#visions a {width: 105px; height: 75px;}
#cottage a {width: 126px; height: 120px;}
#windmill a {width: 63px; height: 80;}

/* hover image position */
#memory a:hover {background: url(./villagemap.gif) -31px -740px no-repeat;}
#timberlost a:hover {background: url(./villagemap.gif) -610px -951px no-repeat; }
#greyhorse a:hover {background: url(./villagemap.gif) -622px -769px no-repeat;}
#visions a:hover {background: url(./villagemap.gif) -65px -970px no-repeat;}
#cottage a:hover {background: url(./villagemap.gif) -384px -939px no-repeat;}
#windmill a:hover {background: url(./villagemap.gif) -351px -783px no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in pure CSS to change the styling upon the hover of another except for the few cases of when the elements are siblings, parents, etc.

In your case you need a very small amount of Jquery, we will use your "Memory Tree" links as an example.

Give each `<a>` with the same `href` value the same class:

```
<a href="./memory.html" id="memory1" class="memory"> <span> ... </span> </a>
<a href="./memory.html" id="memory2" class="memory"> <img> </a>
```

Then in Jquery:

```
$(".memory").on("mouseover", function() {
    $("#memory1").css("background-color","green"); // Whatever green that is
    $("#memory2").css("background", "url(./villagemap.gif) -31px -740px no-repeat");
});
```

Comment: I've looked at this code and attempted to implement it, but I'm having trouble with it. I'm not sure how this javascript line would manage to display the proper piece of the map image in the proper place. I can't get it to do much by way of what I'm attempting. My image map is constructed as one picture, only a portion of which is displayed. The hover calls a specific rectangle from a specific place in the non-displayed section of the picture and then displays it overtop of specific coordinates in the visible portion. I'm not sure how this javascript would interplay with or replace that.

Comment: I made a small mistake, replace `hover` with `mouseover`